# Как отключить проверку типов при сборке TypeScript для её ускорения?

Tags: javascript, typescript, frontend, webpack, babel

Собираю в вебпаке, трансформирую ts в js, спомочью @babel/preset-typescript и файла tsconfig. Как сделать что бы сборка производилась без проверки типов, просто ts в js ?
Просто хочется иметь быстрый вариант сборки.

Comment: нет никакой нужды использовать typescript в таком случае - пишите на js

Comment: @nörbörnën , нет вы не поняли. Я просто хочу иметь два вида сборки с проверкой типов и без неё. Просто проверка типов значительно увеличивает время сборки, и по этому иногда хочется для проверки просто быстро собрать проект без проверки типов.

Comment: Так бабель вроде и не проверяет типы

Comment: А вообще посмотрите на [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/) или [swc](https://swc.rs/)